# Can't install zstd on ol6

Tags: repository, compression, version, oracle-linux, zstd

Is there a way to install the Zstandard compressor on Oracle Linux 6.10, or only since OL7 version?

On OL7 version, I've discovered that zstd resides on "Optional Latest" repository. But, on OL6, it's not found.